# Custom type not showing up in rule config

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

Trying to add a folder rule which should specialize cm:content to our custom type my:content (which inherits from cm:content).

We have configured the following in share-config-custom.xml:

`<type name="cm:content">
     <subtype name="my:content"/>
   </type>`

Our type shows up correctly in the specialize type action in the document library, but when trying to specify a rule the listbox that should contain our type remains empty. :(

What could we be missing?

Comment: Do any of your other share config custom settings work? Maybe your share-config-custom.xml isn't being read?

Comment: All works flawless. Another thing to add is that the customModel.xml is deployed in the data-dictionary/Models, I have successfully created a property form inside share-config-custom.xml that shows up when I click edit properties. As I said the type shows up in the change type action gui in the document library. I tried to add properties-files for the model as well, this time adding them to data-dictionary/Messages. However those are not loaded. How do you add a message resource bundle to a in repository deployed model?

Comment: Have you tried it with the replace=true flag?

Comment: I think the key here may be the hot-loaded content model rather than deploying via the classpath. Have you tested moving your config to the classpath to see if that makes a difference?

Comment: @JeffPotts Yeah I will try that, I think that may be the issue as well. Was doing this for a customer on-site yesterday and did not have the time to do it the classpath way then, but I will eloborate a bit and update here when successful. Thanks!

Comment: Tried to deploy the model on the classpath instead without problems. It seems like (as you proposed @JeffPotts that this is related to hot-loaded models).

Comment: Please create a Jira on this then give me the link so I can vote for/watch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add to web-client-config-custom.xml in alfresco/extension

```
<config evaluator="string-compare" condition="Action Wizards"
    replace="true">
    <subtypes>
        <type name="my:content" />
    </subtypes>
    <specialise-types>
        <type name="my:content" />
    </specialise-types>
</config>
```

And then the trick is to provide title & description for the types in the content model or via messages/properties; otherwise they will not be there.

Wrote about similar issues here: http://experiencewithalfresco.blogspot.dk/2012/08/remember-to-define-title-and.html

Comment: So this is actually a little tricky. You need to do a customization for the Alfresco Explorer client to make it show up in Share?

Comment: Yes, apparently the action used, is configured through Alfresco Explorer :(

Answer (score 0):

For adding custom messages you need to create custom-message-context.xml

```
<beans>
 <bean id="mycompany.resources" class="org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.ResourceBundleBootstrapComponent">
  <property name="resourceBundles">
     <list>
        <value>alfresco.messages.custom</value>
     </list>
  </property>
```

Then create custom.properties file and place it in /shared/classes/alfresco/message folder.

And for adding custom type to rule your config should be working only thing to make sure is config inside which you have put sub-type related config is proper.

Comment: I don't think this is true for the dynamic approach where I store the model in the dictionary?

Comment: Btw. Your answer seems to have been shortened. I'm curious to read the last part:-)

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: This answer is for Alfresco 6.2.2+.

Answering an old thread. For me, I tried this thread all vague answers on Alfresco Hub and nothing worked out.

I have been through this nightmare. Its frustrating and I don't know why Alfresco team relies on "Display Label" instead of "Name".

As shown in the screenshot, I was missing Display Label. As soon as I edited my custom type and provided Display Label, all worked as expected.

[image]

If I would have designed it, I would include, Name and Display Label both in the drop down in my rule window.

Hope it helps someone like me.